# Drupal form_state sanitization

Tags: webforms, security

I'm new to Drupal and I am doing some module development for a Drupal 7 install.  I've done development outside of Drupal and normally its best to always sanitize user input.  I've seen different opinions of the matter but from what I have picked up is dont use form_state['input'] but what about form_state['storage'] or form_state['value'].  I'm seeing some people say the API does the sanitizing and others say always sanitize.  Can anyone explain to be best practice?

Answer (score 2):

The values in `$form_state['values']` are all sanitized.

The values in `$form_state['input']` are the raw unsanitized form values.

`$form_state['storage']` is usually only used on multistep forms to keep data for other form steps.

Where possible always use the values from `$form_state['values']`.

See this post for more information: [Avoid using data from $form_state['input']](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/security/writing-secure-code-0/avoid-using-data-from-form_stateinput)

To quote that linked article:

> The Form API's drupal_validate_form() and _form_validate() functions
>   take care of populating a safe set of data in $form_state['values'],
>   using sanitized data from $form_state['input'].